# Facebook response give User hasn't authorized the application when posting a wall

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing one facebook login logout example which is working fine for me.My problem is when i am posting feed to the facebook wall it response some type of error.
I saw lot of post but not getting result.thanks...

```
protected void PublishFedd() {
    Session s = Session.getActiveSession();
    String testing="My testing app";
    Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(s,testing, new Request.Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response)
            {
                String checkTask=sharedpreference.getString("TASK_NAME", null);
                Log.i(TAG,"ExistingTask:"+checkTask);
                Boolean isNetworkConnected=inetDetector.isInternetConnected();
                if(isNetworkConnected)
                {
                    Log.i(TAG,"ResponseError:"+response.getError());

                if (response.getError() == null)
                {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor edit=sharedpreference.edit();
                    //edit.putString("TASK_NAME", testing);
                    edit.commit();
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookMainActivity.this, "Status updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {

                }
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(FacebookMainActivity.this, "Network Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Error Log is:

```
ResponseError:{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action}
```

Comment: Am also facing same issue any idea of this help me ..

Comment: you will give permission in your coding part...

Comment: see this link it may help you     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781686/error-retrieving-email-and-location-from-facebook-request-in-android/18870420#18870420

Comment: coading part means...

Comment: in your Facebook Main activity

Answer (score 0):

Just ask for permissions.

```
String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins","photo_upload" };
mFacebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, permissions,
            new LoginDialogListener());
```