# Error retrieving email and location from Facebook Request in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook sdk 3.5 in native Android. This is how i get the id/name of my facebook freinds:

```
private void onSessionStateChange(final Session session,
        SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    System.out.println("onSessionStateChanged");
    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED)) {
            tokenUpdated();
        } else {
            getUserRequest(session);
            getFriendsRequest(session);
        }
    } else {
        profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
        userNameView.setText("");
    }
}
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(getActivity(), requestCode,
                resultCode, data);
        // uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data,
        // nativeDialogCallback);
    }


private void getFriendsRequest(Session session) {

        session.requestNewReadPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(
                getActivity(), PERMISSIONS));
        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // get friends details
        Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(session,
                new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users,
                            Response response) {

                        // if no errors
                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                            if (users != null) {
                                for (GraphUser user : users) {
                                    FacebookFriend fb = new FacebookFriend(user
                                            .getId(), user.getName(), "", "",
                                            "", 0);
                                        friends.add(fb);
                                    }

....
                    }
}
```

The **response** is now:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"id":"213","name":"Test name"}]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

All great here, but details  like email(if shared), location, username are not in :

```
GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphUser, state={"id":"60711232217","name":"Test"}}
```

Where should i set permissions? This is my request:

```
{Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_location, user_friends, friends_location, basic_info]}, appId:111111}, graphPath: me/friends, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{access_token=dasdasdasdasdsada, format=json, sdk=android, migration_bundle=fbsdk:20130708}]}
```

Where should i add those permissions to have more details?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you defined `email` permission?

Comment: This is how i added permissions: private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] { "email",
   "basic_info", "user_location", "friends_location" };  final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
   session.requestNewReadPermissions(new NewPermissionsRequest(
     getActivity(), PERMISSIONS));

Comment: If in Facebook sdk i leave the url to: me/friends and then i make a request, this is how it looks like: {Request:  session: {Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_location, user_friends, friends_location, basic_info]}, appId:464998303608448}, graphPath: me/friends, graphObject: null, restMethod: null, httpMethod: GET, parameters: Bundle[{access_token=.., format=json, sdk=android, migration_bundle=fbsdk:20130708}]} so the email and location permissions are there. But the response is still with id/username details.

Comment: If you use the the same request in Graph Tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/, do you get the same error? By the way, there is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends [written here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/)

Comment: using the accesss token from the request i get data(but mine, not my friends): {
  "id": "..",
  "name": "...",
  "email": "....",
  "location": {
    "id": "...",
    "name": "Sibiu, Romania"
  }
} Does this mean that i need a different access token?

Comment: Your access token is ok. By using request: `me/friends?fields=id,name,location,email` you must get info of your friends and not yours, and `email` of your friends won't be retrieved with any access token

Comment: I understand what you mean, very confuzed on why i do not receive any info other than id/username of my friends.

Comment: I hope i don;t have to create a request for each of my friends to get data. Using GraphApi Explorer, if i write the id of a user and ask for location i receive data, but that would mean hundreds of requests for this and it's unacceptable. :(

Answer (score 6):

> Go to this link
>   [Graphapilink](https://www.facebook.com/login.php?next=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%252Ffriends%253Ffields%253Dname%252Clocation)
>
> Click the Graph API Explorer icon->
>   Then select your application name "YourApplication"->
>   Then click the GetAccesTocken .it show the Select Permission Pop Up window.->Then you select the Extended Permission tab.

[image]

> Finally you will be select the necessary permission you want as the picture above

Comment: If you have any doubt ask me

Comment: @Satheesh Hello Satheesh, I couldn't found the permission to get user's profile pic. Can you please tell me how cal I give that permission ?

Comment: @kunu sorry i am not aware that

Answer (score 2):

- **Facebook doesn't allow apps to access friends emails**

For the Rest See The Below Images.. 
You have to set the right permissions and see how it works in my profile

[image]

[image]

And The result you will get

[image]

Comment: this works, from the graph api on the website, but not in the code .:(

Comment: @Augustus Francis I couldn't found the permission to get user's profile pic. Can you please tell me how cal I give that permission ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query:

```
"me/friends?fields=id,name,location,email"
```

That means you are trying to fetch name, location, email. You can get the **name**, but for the **location** you need the permission `friends_location`; for **email**- facebook dont allow you to fetch the email of the friends.

> I hope i don;t have to create a request for each of my friends to get data

Of-course not. Your query is right, you'll get an array in the result just like-

```
{
  "data": [
    {
        "name": Friend1_Name, 
        "location": {
           "id": Friend1_LocationID, 
           "name": Friend1_Location
        }, 
        "id": Friend1_ID
    }, 
    {
        "name": Friend2_Name, 
        "location": {
           "id": Friend2_LocationID, 
           "name": Friend2_Location
        }, 
        "id": Friend2_ID
    }, 
    ....
    ....
 ]
}
```

[Live Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%2Ffriends%3Ffields%3Dname%2Clocation)

---

If you're getting-

> "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"

That means the (current) user has not logged into your app, or the session is expired. So, login/auth the user then make the API call.

Comment: auch, it would be weird, i can understand the logic of the above but for me it's weird because i can re-login when i want.

Comment: What are youo trying to say? What's the confusion?

Comment: this is the error i receive:`{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_location, user_friends, friends_location, basic_info]}, appId:42434}`. my confusion is why the access token is removed. I can login, but it is removed to do ask for friends list?

Comment: Have you authorized the user? Please update the question with the login/auth code you have used. You error simply means that there is no any user in the current session. `/me` can be used only after a user login to your app and comes into the session