# Getting user profile picture, user location and b'day data from facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I am following  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/  tutorial for getting user data from facebook. But to get user profile picture , user birthday and user location different permissions are required. So can anyone help me how can I give those permission to this particular tutorial and where to give them

Comment: did u have check this link, 
[In this Link the Snapshot Will show all the required permission to set][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781686/error-retrieving-email-and-location-from-facebook-request-in-android

hope this helps.

Comment: @i.n.e.f I checked it now, but no luck